# Using WebJobs with Azure Service Bus and Sessions

Tags: c#, session, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm new to the Azure Service Bus and am working on a proof of concept using Service Bus Queues, WebJobs, v2.5 of the Azure SDK and Visual Studio 2013

Enqueuing and de-queuing messages from the bus is pretty straightforward, but in order to implement a request-response pattern it looks like I need to use sessions, and that's where the wheels have come off.

Here's the proof-of-concept code from the WebJobs project. It requires that you create two service bus queues: *test-request* and *test-response*. The response queue must have **Enable Sessions = true**

```
class Program
{
    private static string _azureServiceBusConnection;

    static void Main()
    {
        _azureServiceBusConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureWebJobsServiceBus"].ConnectionString;

        var host = new JobHost();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Run());

        try
        {
            host.RunAndBlock();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RunAndBlock() Unexpected {0}: {1}", ex.GetType().FullName, ex.Message);  
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static async Task Run()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        var request = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_azureServiceBusConnection, "test-request");
        var response = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_azureServiceBusConnection, "test-response");

        var sessionid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        MessageSession receiver;
        try
        {
            receiver = response.AcceptMessageSession(sessionid);
        }
        catch (Exception ex )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AcceptMessageSession() Unexpected {0}: {1}", ex.GetType().FullName, ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        var payload = new RequestModel {ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Delay = 1};
        var message = new BrokeredMessage(payload) {ReplyToSessionId = sessionid};
        try
        {
            request.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Send() Unexpected {0}: {1}", ex.GetType().FullName, ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        var receivedMessage = receiver.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        if (receivedMessage != null)
        {
            // Request processed within the timeout period
            var responseBody = receivedMessage.GetBody<RequestModel>();
            Console.WriteLine("Inline response to {0}", responseBody.ID );
            receivedMessage.Complete();
        }
        else
        {
            // Request processing timed out - should be handled by LocalResponseQueue WebJob (see below)
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Response timed out.");
        } 
    }
}

public class RequestModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public int Delay { get; set; }
}

public class RemoteSystemRequestQueue
{
    // Simulates the processing of the request on a remote system
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("test-request")] BrokeredMessage request, [ServiceBus("test-response")] out BrokeredMessage response)
    {
        // Wait for the prescribed delay, then bounce the request payload back via the response queue
        var requestBody = request.GetBody<RequestModel>();
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved Request {0}, delay={1}", requestBody.ID, requestBody.Delay);
        Task.Delay(requestBody.Delay * 1000).Wait();
        response = new BrokeredMessage(requestBody) {SessionId = request.ReplyToSessionId};
        request.Complete();
        Console.WriteLine("Completed Request {0}, delay={1}", requestBody.ID, requestBody.Delay);
    }
}

public class LocalResponseQueue
{
    // Should be called ONLY when the processing took longer than the timeout
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("test-response")] BrokeredMessage message, TextWriter logger)
    {
        var msgBody = message.GetBody<RequestModel>();
        Console.WriteLine("ResponseFactory Recieved Reply {0}", msgBody.ID);
    }
}
```

When **Enable Sessions = true** on the test-response queue, the call to **host.RunAndBlock()** throws a System.InvalidOperationException with the message

*It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver*

The output looks like this:

```
Found the following functions:
ServiceBusPoc.RemoteSystemRequestQueue.ProcessQueueMessage
ServiceBusPoc.LocalResponseQueue.ProcessQueueMessage
Executing: 'RemoteSystemRequestQueue.ProcessQueueMessage' because New service bus message detected on 'test-request'.
Recieved Request 4f000f8f-dd69-4909-9ec4-020fec12366c, delay=1
RunAndBlock() Unexpected System.InvalidOperationException: It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver.
TrackingId:7836ac90-6920-4e6c-b7f1-cf648e2a17e5_G38_B10,TimeStamp:10/6/2015 12:37:05 PM
```

Note that the exception was thrown BEFORE the RemoteSystemRequestQueue object could complete processing the queued request

I presume from this that this means that WebJobs can't handle sessions (at least in the manner in which I'm using them)

Can anyone shed any light on this, or am I going to have to give up on WebJobs?

Answer (score 0):

What version of the WebJobs SDK are you using? In our current v1.1.0 release (still prerelease) we've started opening up more options for ServiceBus configuration. See:

- [ServiceBusConfiguration](http://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/Config/ServiceBusConfiguration.cs)
- [Custom MessagingProvider](http://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/test/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.EndToEndTests/ServiceBusEndToEndTests.cs#L105)

You can basically now control more of the messaging details that were previously buried in the SDK internals. However, regarding full Session support, we do have [this open issue](http://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/529) that might be closer to your scenario. If so, and if you can't get things to work with the above, please add your scenario details to that issue. Thanks.